# Как выбрать нужные записи из таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql

Как выбрать нужные записи из таблицы?

Есть база, в ней есть две таблицы - users и orders. Нужно вывести данные из таблицы orders, но с таким условием, чтобы: 1. условие по ID, то есть выводится заказ по  ID Иванов Иван, его id =23, и заказ его выводится, правда, сделал так, что его заказ выводится по сумме товара (не подумал, что она может быть одинакова у некотрых пользователей :) ).

Так вот, как тут даписать, чтобы ещё была запись по  дате, а именно по времени, так как время у всех будет разное 14:23:11 и так далее, своего рода ID,  то есть нужно, чтобы в условии дата в таблице users совпадала с датой в таблице orders:

```
include 'admin_db_fns.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE user_id='$id' типа time=time или как?");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил это безбожно сложную задачу!)

Нужно было написать в файле, который отправляет данные, в ссылке передать параметр

```
<a href="item_orders.php?id=<?=$row['user_id'];?>&tame=<?=$row['tame'];?>" target="_blank">Заказ</a>
```

А в файле, который принимает, сделать так:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$tame = $_GET['tame'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE user_id='$id' AND time='$tame'");
```